# User dashboard for Blogging application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a Blogging application.

Each user can create several blogs, and on each blog they can have several posts, each of which has a mix of content, i.e: video content, text content, photo content.

The user has_many blogs. 
The blog has_many posts.

The posts belong_to blog.

And all of the posts content i.e. video, text, and photos are connected to the Post via STI.

The trouble I'm having is figuring out how to connect the user to their own personal dashboard.

On this dashboard they should be able to create new blogs, edit existing blogs, view and search for other users blogs etc...

I'm using Devise to create and update users, what's the best way to go about creating a dashboard for them in this case? I'm stumped!!

Comment: You just have to create the appropriate model, view and controller (the ones that you need) that manipulate and show all the data you want.

Comment: I'm not clear what the issue is. You presumably have the user in session. Have a dashboard page that retrieves the user's specific info. What's the precise problem?

Comment: Cheers @DaveNewton, Good question - I do NOT have the dashboard page or it's related controller in place yet, the above post it hypothetical of how I'd like it to work. I'm in the process of building that now. I just want to make sure that I setup the backend in the most efficient way so that I don't have to re-do it later on. So I guess the question is, what would be the best way to create this dashboard and have it work with Devise, now that you know how my app is to work from the example in my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are several ways to do it. I would do it in the following way.

- Create a dashboard controller and relevant views. If required, I would create a dashboard model (a non-ActiveRecord model is perhaps appropriate in this case).
- Add an authenticated route to change the root path of a user. For example, the following entry in the config/routes.rb would ensure that the root path for a logged in user would be the respective user's dashboard. Read more about authenticated routes [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb)

  ```
  authenticated :user do
    root to: "user_dashboard#index", as: :user_dashboard
  end
  ```
- The dashboard page could for example, list out the most recent blogs, provide links to perform the CRUD actions on user blogs etc.

Comment: I like this idea. The route would then be something like user_dashboard/user? Any point in creating a model at all for this? If so, care to provide an example of what the associations would look like between user and dashboard. Thanks!

Comment: There would not be any associations between the user and the dashboard. It is essentially just a controller with a bunch of views. I cannot really think of any specific use case at this point in time, where a dashboard model would make sense. 
Generally speaking, dashboard is a way to present the user with an overview of the most important components of a system. It is essentially a user's personalized home page where he/she can view all the blogs, updates and other relevant stuff.

Comment: As far as the route is concerned, it really depends on how you wish to design the experience. For one of my apps, I added an authenticated root route, meaning that, authenticated user's root path is now their own dashboard page and not the generic homepage of the site. The other option would be to add a route to the user dashboard and have the user redirect to the dashboard after sign in. For more info on this, [check this out](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)